# Posts Rating - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rating

I am implementing rating system in rails for posts.

On viewing a post one can rate the post by clicking radio button.
Below is the code. Consider **only the post and rating** don't consider tags, topics..

And there is no user in my concept one can rate whenever he needed and it should be added with existing rating of the post.

But, When I am doing this in log it shows the following:

**Server log:**

```
Started PATCH "/posts/34" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-08 18:36:55 +0530
Processing by PostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"l3aae99V424OyKVt5ULmqX2Mcs7DY2GYBskbLyhqqNENDn24ldCDAt4gNcgjESlFR6eaP0vcvrcoOerGE9lH5A==", "post"=>{"rating_ids"=>["5"]}, "commit"=>"Rate", "id"=>"34"}
  Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 34]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "34"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (4.0ms)  INSERT INTO "ratings" ("star", "post_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["star", 5], ["post_id", 34], ["created_at", "2015-12-08 13:06:55.626133"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-08 13:06:55.626133"]]
   (216.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Rating Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Rating Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 34]]
  SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "ratings" SET "post_id" = NULL WHERE "ratings"."post_id" = ? AND "ratings"."id" IN (4, 25)  [["post_id", 34]]
  SQL (3.0ms)  UPDATE "ratings" SET "post_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "ratings"."id" = ?  [["post_id", 34], ["updated_at", "2015-12-08 13:06:55.878147"], ["id", 5]]
   (170.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/topics/9
Completed 302 Found in 489ms (ActiveRecord: 397.0ms)
```

where it changes the `post.id` to `NULL`

```
SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "ratings" SET "post_id" = NULL WHERE "ratings"."post_id" = ? AND "ratings"."id" IN (4, 25)  [["post_id", 34]]
```

I don't know how this happens and how to overcome this So, Please help.

**It changes the Rating database as below:**

**1st column: id, 2nd column: star, 3rd column: post_id**

```
1,1,NULL
2,2,NULL
3,3,NULL
4,4,NULL
5,5,34
6,4,NULL
7,1,NULL
8,1,NULL
9,5,NULL
10,1,NULL
11,5,NULL
12,1,NULL
13,4,NULL
14,3,NULL
15,4,NULL
16,4,NULL
17,4,NULL
18,2,NULL
19,1,NULL
20,5,NULL
21,3,NULL
```

**Post model:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :topic   
    has_many :comments
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :ratings
end
```

**Rating model:**

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**Post show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @posts.name %> (
  <%= @posts.topic.name %> )
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @posts.email %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Message:</strong>
  <%= @posts.message %>
</p>

 <strong>Tags:</strong>
<% @posts.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <div>
        <%= tag.name %> <br>
    </div>
 <% end %>
<br>

<strong>Rating:</strong>
<%= @posts.ratings.group(:star).count %>


<%= form_for @posts do |f| %>
    <% (1..5).each do |rating| %>

        <%= radio_button_tag "post[rating_ids][]", rating %>
        <%= rating %>

<% end %>

<%= f.submit('Rate') %>

<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Comments', post_comments_path(@posts) %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@posts) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', topic_posts_url(@posts.topic) %>
```

**Post controller:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    if params[:topic_id].to_i > 0
          @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
          @posts = @topic.posts.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    else
      @posts = Post.eager_load(:topic).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    end
    end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
      @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
      @tags = @posts.tags
      @comment = Comment.new(:post => @posts)
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @posts = @topic.posts.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
    @tags = @posts.tags
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @posts = @topic.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @posts.save
        format.html { redirect_to topic_url(@posts.topic_id), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @posts }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @posts.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update

    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
    @tags = @posts.tags
    respond_to do |format|
      @posts.ratings.create(:star => params[:post][:rating_ids][0].to_i)
      if @posts.update(post_params)

        format.html { redirect_to topic_url(@posts.topic_id), notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @posts }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @posts.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @posts.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to topic_url(@posts.topic_id), notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
     @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :message, :topic_id, {tag_ids:[]}, rating_ids:[])
    end
end
```

I am new to rails and I need to implement this without using any gem..
Please help how it changes the **post_id to NULL** which I denoted in server log..

Comment: I think you should combine the advice implicit in the answers of Vasfed and Omar Mowafi.  Out of curiosity, are you using `accepts_nested_parameters_for :ratings` in your `Post` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because after you created a `Rating` manually then goes `@posts.update(rating_ids:[5])`, which states that this post only should have rating with id 5, not 5 stars

Plus are you sure want your unauthenticated users to have access to post editing?

Answer (score 1):

Since you save the rating before updating the post change your `post_params` to:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :message, :topic_id, {tag_ids:[]})
end
```

As you are saving the rating from the params directly.

However you should consider changing your structure to use something like nested attributes which will automatically save/update ratings.